# Laravel Difference between url() and URL::to()

Tags: laravel

I have seen both used in different project, but what is the difference between:

`{{ url('/account') }}` and `{{URL::to('account')}}`

Comment: Laravel provides a variety of these helper functions, like `view()` and `redirect()`. They do the same thing as their more verbose siblings.

Comment: Function-wise, these are exactly the same. The `url()` (and many other helper functions) were added post Laravel 4.2 (I believe), so be aware that trying to use `url()` on older projects will result in an error. Also, namspacing can be an issue with the older style ones: `URL::to()` may throw an error, but `\Url::to()` should not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`url()` is just a helper function that makes a very similar call as `URL::to()`. They are both functionally the same.

in the `Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php` file `url()` is defined as

```
function url($path = null, $parameters = [], $secure = null)
{
    if (is_null($path)) {
        return app(UrlGenerator::class);
    }

    return app(UrlGenerator::class)->to($path, $parameters, $secure);
}
```

Both the `url()` function and the `URL` facade call the `UrlGenerator` class. they both provide different syntactic sugar for the same method call.